# Java Future object return value from API after onComplete

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a API method like below where the method returns `ResponseEntity<JsonNode>`. I don't know how to wait for it and return value in Future `onComplete` method.

```
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> doSomeAction(
        @ApiParam(name = "mode", required = true) @PathVariable final String mode,
        @RequestBody SomeAction action, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException) {

            if(mode.equals("POWER"){
                Future<JsonObject> future = someAppService.generatePower(action);
                future.onComplete( result -> {
                    return new ResponseEntity<JsonNode>(JsonHelper.toJsonNode(result.result().encode()), HttpStatus.OK)
                    //above return is not valid but i want to return here as soon as future completes

                });
            }
            if(mode.equals("someOtherMode"){

                //some code here

            }
            return new ResponseEntity<JsonNode>(JsonHelper.getObjectMapper().valueToTree(someResponse), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Basically , i want to return value in `onComplete` method i.e after generatePower() method is executed which internally invokes some API which might take some time.
I tried to use `DeferredResult<JsonNode>` but its not working.  Any idea?

Comment: You need to change your method to `Future<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>>` or block the thread while waiting for the future to complete.

Comment: Closely related: https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/ (you are calling a "red" function)

Comment: @knittl  How should i block the thread till the future is complete? can u give some idea?

Comment: [`future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: This seems to be Future object from  io.vertx:vertx-core:3.9.0
So get method is not available. Only result() is available but no timeout can be passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CountDownLatch to wait for the result:

```
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> doSomeAction(
            @ApiParam(name = "mode", required = true) @PathVariable final String mode,
            @RequestBody SomeAction action, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException) {

                ResponseEntity<JSonObbject> result = null;
                CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(1);
                if(mode.equals("POWER"){
                    Future<JsonObject> future = someAppService.generatePower(action);
                    future.onComplete( result -> {
                        result = new ResponseEntity<JsonNode>(JsonHelper.toJsonNode(result.result().encode()), HttpStatus.OK)
                        ready.countDown();
                    });
                } else if(mode.equals("someOtherMode"){
    
                    //code that updates result variable
    
                } else {
                   // take care of all other cases
                }
                
                if (!ready.await(timeout, SECONDS) {
                    // return error or throw appropriate exception
                }
                return result;
    }
```

Comment: I have a query. what if the generatePower method returns value in 1 second but we wait for 5 seconds. I want to return the value as and when the future object is ready/complete. and i guess ResponseEntity should be final since we can't use non final variables inside lambda expression. correct me

Comment: ready.await will return when the count reaches zero or when the timeout expires, so in your example result will be returned within close to 1 seconds.